# HikariCP always using mysql root?

Tags: java, mariadb, mysql-connector, hikaricp

I'm encountering some issues running my Java project since mariadb replaced the regular mysql. I have found the new .cnf which is 50-server.cnf, changed the bind-address to 0.0.0.0, reloaded mysql and mariadb and I runned the usual mysql commands to grant all privileges to the mysql user I use (I did not forget to flush privileges). I also tried to open the port 3306 with iptables even though it's all just local operations.

The java error shows troubles connecting with root

```
com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool$PoolInitializationException: Failed to initialize pool: Could not connect to address=(host=localhost)(port=3306)(type=master) : (conn=37) Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.throwPoolInitializationException(HikariPool.java:595)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.checkFailFast(HikariPool.java:581)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.<init>(HikariPool.java:115)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource.<init>(HikariDataSource.java:81)
    at fr.mathwellan.dispenser.utils.HikariSQL.<init>(HikariSQL.java:37)
```

even though I don't actually try to connect with root

```
HikariConfig hikariConfig = new HikariConfig();
hikariConfig.setMaximumPoolSize(10);
hikariConfig.setDriverClassName("org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver");
hikariConfig.setJdbcUrl("jdbc:mariadb://localhost:3306/database");
hikariConfig.setUsername("notroot"); // here, it's a custom user
hikariConfig.setPassword("psswd");

hikariConfig.setConnectionTimeout(1000L);
hikariConfig.addDataSourceProperty("autoReconnect", true);
hikariConfig.addDataSourceProperty("cachePrepStmts", true);
hikariConfig.addDataSourceProperty("prepStmtCacheSize", 250);
hikariConfig.addDataSourceProperty("prepStmtCacheSqlLimit", 2048);
hikariConfig.addDataSourceProperty("useServerPrepStmts", true);
hikariConfig.addDataSourceProperty("cacheResultSetMetadata", true);

new HikariDataSource(hikariConfig); // line 37
```

I tried using differents versions of HikariCP, it doesn't change a thing

I hope someone knows better than me what's going on, I have done some google search but everyone who have this error seems to be using root in their code

Comment: I would suggest you to change mariadb data source url to `org.mariadb.jdbc.MariaDbDataSource` and check

Comment: Thank you for your comment dkb, unfortunately in the end it's the same error. But somehow before there are multiple SQLException : no database selected

Comment: also, you can remove `JdbcUrl` and add additional props like `hikariConfig.set DatabaseName`, `hikariConfig.setPortNumber`, `hikariConfig.setServerName`,

Comment: another option to try ```final HikariDataSource ds = new HikariDataSource();
        ds.setMaximumPoolSize(20);
        ds.setDriverClassName("org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver");
        ds.setJdbcUrl("jdbc:mariadb://localhost:3306/db");
        ds.addDataSourceProperty("user", "root");
        ds.addDataSourceProperty("password", "myPassword");
        ds.setAutoCommit(false);```

Comment: Thank you for your interest, about your first comment HikariConfig doesn't seem to have all those 'set' methods. I added what you suggested in your second comment tho, it changes nothing if I just add it and there's an IllegalArgumentException if I remove the HikariConfig equivalent of the HikariDataSource solution

Comment: Works fine for me, example: https://gist.github.com/dineshbhagat/7ed71007003e209082a1ccf8c48da765

Comment: I don't understand why I get those exceptions about the root user, if it was the same exceptions but with my custom user I would say it is because of the configuration stuff I mention in the beginning of my original post but yea it got to be my fault if using another user works with you

Comment: Suggestion: Create a brand new [mre] using as little code as possible, but which still demonstrates the issue. Then [edit] your question to show that MRE. (If the community cannot recreate your problem, it may be much harder to help you.)